# Is it right to add subview in layoutSubviews when using Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I wrote codes like these that works well

```
@interface SubView()
@property(nonatomic,strong) UIButton* btn;
@end

@implementation SubView


- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self.btn removeFromSuperview];
    self.btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.btn setTitle:@"btn" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self addSubview:self.btn];

    NSLayoutConstraint* centerXConstraint = [self.btn.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.centerXAnchor];
    NSLayoutConstraint* centerYConstraint = [self.btn.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.centerYAnchor];
    [self addConstraint:centerXConstraint];
    [self addConstraint:centerYConstraint];
}
@end
```

But in my opinion,When using Autolayout, the system  will do the layout in two steps **1 Update Pass 2 Layout Pass** , and the layoutSubviews is in the step 2(Layout Pass)

so if we add subview in layoutSubviews ,it seems like it will change the view's constraints , so we need do the update pass  and layout pass again , so it will generate a infinite loop ..

but in fact , this code works well , so where am i wrong?

Comment: Add `subView` will not change the view's constraints, thus `layoutSubviews` will not be called. However `layoutSubviews` is not a good place to add subviews, better to do it in the initialiser.

Comment: you mean the centerXConstraint above is not the view'constraints , but the subview's constraint? so the view's layoutSubviews can layout right

Comment: Yes, it just align the button to the view's centerX, which does not affect the position/size of the view itself. `layouSubiviews` gets called when the view's frame changed,  or if you do `setNeedsLayout` or `layoutIfNeeded` to manually trigger a layout.

Comment: OK, got it , thanks alot @EricQian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind that `layoutSubviews` will be called many times. What sense does it make to remove the button and add it again every single time?

Also, `layoutSubviews` is where the autolayout system obeys constraints. So what sense does it make to set the button's constraints in `layoutSubviews`?

Even if it *seems* to be working, none of what you are doing makes any sense in `layoutSubviews`. Do this task once and do it elsewhere.

Comment: thanks @matt, i've seen some codes (like i've post above) in updateConstraints, so it's also a bad habbit to add/remove subView in updateConstraints?

Comment: @ximmyxiao yes. Do it elsewhere, like in viewDidLoad.

Comment: @Shebuka if it's in a custom uiview , it seem like the init method will be the only nice place to do such things?

Comment: "so it's also a bad habbit to add/remove subView in updateConstraints" That's not the point. The point is that _your_ code removes the `btn` view and then adds it back again. That's the silly part. You only need to add this `btn` view _once_, so do it once and leave it alone.